# sessionStorage content not getting removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-storage

I have populated the sessionStorage in the following way

```
var shopcart = [];
if (!itemincart) {
    shopcart.push(iteminfo);
}
sessionStorage["sca"] = JSON.stringify(shopcart);
```

And now I want to make the sessionStorage completely empty. I have tried several suggestions on this site but could not find any solution till now. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `sessionStorage.clear()`?

Comment: yes, I tried that but it did not work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/yre5g47d/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sessionStorage.clear();` to remove all the data set in `sessionStorage` or use `sessionStorage.removeItem();` to remove just one item in the `sessionStorage`:

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```

or:

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('sca');
```

You can read more about this **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)**.

**UPDATE**:

If you mean you want to clear the `sessionStorage[]` array, then you can do it by setting it to a new empty array like this:

```
sessionStorage = [];
```

Comment: Setting `sessionStorage` to an empty array is sometimes the safest way to go for a logout process (web app using a router). I had some strange behaviours logging in and logging out of user accounts with `. clear()`

Answer (score 0):

sessionStorage.clear() will remove all session data.